# Retrieving a delegate type using custom types from an assembly that is currently being built

Tags: f#, delegates, system.reflection, cil

I am trying to make a compiler in F# using the API provided in System.Reflection.Emit. I am running into a problem when I try to create functions (delegates) for the types in the assembly that I am currently building. Example translating the following Java (a slightly modified version of Java) class:

```
class A extends Object {
    Integer x;
    A (Integer x) {
        super();
        this.x = x;
    }
    Function<A, Integer> fun() {
        return (A a) -> { return a.x; };
    }
}
```

So, I need to be able to use the System.Type of Func<A, Integer> in order to generate the following CIL instruction:

```
newobj instance void class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<class tst.A,int32>::.ctor(object, native int)
```

The code generating the respective instruction is:

```
let deleg = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.GetDelegateType(types)
let constr = deleg.GetConstructor([|typeof<obj> ; typeof<nativeint>|])
ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, constr)
```

where `types` is an array of System.Type elements. In case of Fun<A, Integer>, the types array is `[|typ ; typeof<int>|]`, where typ is declared like: `let typ : System.Type = upcast typeBuilder` . However, this triggers the following  error:

```
System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.
at System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilderInstantiation.GetConstructorImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, CallingConventions callConvention, Type[] types, ParameterModifier[] modifiers)
at System.Type.GetConstructor(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Type[] types, ParameterModifier[] modifiers)
```

If I needed to generate the same instruction for a function that uses .NET types, for instance Func<Integer, Integer>, then the above code works perfectly (the types array is `types = [| typeof<int> ; typeof<int> |]` in this case). Any suggestions why the above solution doesn't work or any other alternatives of how to retrieve the System.Type of a TypeBuilder (that is not finished building) are more than welcome.

The way the typeBuilder for the class A is generated is:

```
let typeBuilder = moduleBuilder.DefineType(typ, TypeAttributes.Public ||| TypeAttributes.Class)
typeBuilder.SetParent(typeof<obj>)
typeBuilder.DefineField("x", typeof<int>, FieldAttributes.Public)
let constrBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public, CallingConventions.Standard, [|typeof<int>|])
let methodBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("fun", MethodAttributes.Public)
let delegRetType =  System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.GetDelegateType([|typeof<obj> ; typeof<int>|]).GetConstructor([|typeof<obj> ; typeof<nativeint>|]).DeclaringType
methodBuilder.SetReturnType(delegRetType) 
methodBuilder.SetParameters([||])
//buildConstrBody - nothing special
//buildMethodBody - generating the instructions using the methodBuilder .GetILGenerator() - triggering the error described above
typeBuilder.CreateType()
```

Note that `delegRetType` is actually Func<Object, Integer> instead of Func<A, Integer>. If I try to change it to the latter, the same error is triggered...

Comment: This is hard to debug, because you did not share a code that we could try running, but I noticed that the error message says `Could not load type 'A' (...) because the parent type is sealed.`. What is the parent type you're using for `A`? Is that a sealed type?

Comment: No, it is not, the parent of that class is a Object class, which just extends the F# System.Type retrieved from `typeof<obj>`. But the type A has a nested class for encapsulating the function, which is declared like this: `let nestedTypeBuilder = classTypeBuilder.DefineNestedType(cls, TypeAttributes.AutoClass ||| TypeAttributes.AnsiClass ||| TypeAttributes.Sealed ||| TypeAttributes.NestedPublic)`, but the error persists even if I remove the sealed modifier...

Comment: I edited the post, providing more info about the code. The error with the sealed parent is not triggered anymore (don't really know why). I hope now my question is more clear, given that I posted a simple example that works with .NET types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually works if the array is built like this:

```
types = [| typeBuilder.GetType(); typeof<int> |]
```

Answer (score 0):

> If I needed to generate the same instruction for a function that uses .NET types, for instance Func<Integer, Integer>, then the above code works perfectly (the types array is `types = [| typeof<int> ; typeof<int> |]` in this case).

`TypeBuilder` inherits from `Type`, so you just pass the instance that represents the type you're building when you want a reference to that type.  In other words, the array you want is `types = [| typeBuilder :> System.Type; typeof<int> |]`

Comment: but why is `upcast typeBuilder` not working as well?